# QField positioning permissions

Tags: qfield

I'm currently trying to use QField on Trimble TDC600s. When I try and enable GPS position display on the map, the display clears off and leaves a single dot on it.  Every other feature is working as intended including the display of position information at the bottom of the screen.

Please note: I have tried reinstalling as that seemed to fix this for at least some others in the past.  This also occurs on multiple units.  Additionally when I long press to turn on and off positioning, I get an error message that QField does not have permissions to positioning when turning it off, but not on.

QField version 1.3.1
QGIS version 3.10. Data layers are in a geopackage on the Trimble.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to have been a CRS issue. It works when using WGS84 but not ESRI 120761

Per request, here is the reported issue at github.

https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/738

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/176417)

Comment: @lambertj If problem is solved by changing the CRS, then this is a complete answer.

Comment: @LostCollection This seems like a bug, did you report it? If so, please [edit] your answer and add a link to the bug report.

Comment: Where did you change the CRS ? Was it a problem with QField not working properly with a project in ESRI 120761 (ie. a QField bug) or was it a problem with CRS in your project (ie.  something related to the common mistake of changing CRS rather than reprojecting)